# Vue 2.5 - Slots / Slot scope - Encapsulate a library component into a custom component

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using vue 2.5 and the library Bootstrap-vue.
I'm interested by the table component of this library: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table

But I want to encapsulate this component to make my own component with custom configuration which I don't want to repeat. This way I don't have to manage pagination and filtering every time and I can add other features like data export.

So I created a table-helper component (only pagination is handled for now)

```
<template>
    <div>
        <b-table striped hover responsive
                 :items="items" :fields="fields"
                 :current-page="currentPage" per-page="10">
            <slot></slot>
        </b-table>
        <b-pagination :total-rows="items.length" per-page="10" v-model="currentPage"></b-pagination>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import bTable from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/table/table'
    import bPagination from 'bootstrap-vue/es/components/pagination/pagination'

    export default {
        name: "table-helper",
        props: ['items', 'fields'],
        data() {
            return {
                currentPage: 1,
            }
        },
        components: {
            'b-table': bTable,
            'b-pagination': bPagination
        }
    }
</script>
```

And I want to use my component like this (using the bootstrap-vue slot possibility to reformat columns):

```
<table-helper :items="users" :fields="fields">
    <template slot="fullName" slot-scope="data">
        {{data.item.first_name}} {{data.item.last_name}}
    </template>
</table-helper>
```

Obviously it doesn't work (I get the table but not the formatted columns) because the `<template slot="fullName" slot-scope="data">` refers to my custom component and not to the b-table component.

So I'd like to know a way to encapsulated a library component which uses slots and slot scopes like this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Key points:**

1. **Template vs JSX**: You may have to use JSX to implement it, especially for **slot**.
2. **Slot**: for your case, the slot of parent component will be the children VNodes of `b-table`, so reshape the slot to one array and change the context from parent to current (if not **scopedSlot** will be rendered incorrectly.), then put them into the third parameter of function=h (or you can call `createElement`). For the details, check [Vue Guide: Create Element Arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments).

Anyway, read [Best Way To Implement HOC](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6201) carefully , then you should be able to reach the goal.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('table-helper', {
  render (h) {
    const slots = Object.keys(this.$slots)
      .reduce((arr, key) => arr.concat(this.$slots[key]), [])
      .map(vnode => {
        vnode.context = this._self
        return vnode
      })
    const self = this
    
    return h('div', [
      h('b-table', {
        on: self.$listeners,
        props: Object.assign(self.$props, {currentPage: self.currentPage}),
        scopedSlots: self.$scopedSlots,
        attrs: self.$attrs
      },slots),
      h('b-pagination', {
        props: self.$props,
        domProps: {
          value: self.currentPage
        },
        on: {
          input: function (event) {
            self.currentPage = event
          }
        }
      })
    ])
  },
  //mixins: [{bTable.props}, {bPagination.props}],
  props: ['items', 'fields', 'perPage','totaRows'],
  data() {
    return {
      currentPage: 1,
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [ 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'fullName' ],
      users: [
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' },
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' },
        { isActive: true, age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
        { isActive: false, age: 21, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
        { isActive: false, age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
        { isActive: true, age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/babel-polyfill@latest/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <table-helper :items="users" :fields="fields" :per-page="10" :total-rows="users.length">
      <template slot="fullName" slot-scope="data">
          {{data.item.first_name}} {{data.item.last_name}}
      </template>
  </table-helper>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this with JSX ? Do `h('b-pagination', {props: self.$props}` have an equivalent in JSX ?

Comment: you are saying this [babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx#difference-from-react-jsx)?

Comment: I mean I want to do something like this in JSX to have a prettier code : `<b-table on={self.$listeners}
     props={Object.assign(self.$props, {currentPage: self.currentPage, filter: self.filter})}
       scopedSlots={self.$scopedSlots}
       attrs={self.$attrs}>
    </b-table>`